# Is it possible to make a MS-SQL Scalar function do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a 3rd party application that can call a MS-SQL scalar function to return some summary information from a table.  I was able to return the summary values with a table-valued function, but the application won't utilize table-valued functions, so I'm kind of stuck.  Here's a sample from the table:

**trackingNumber,   projTaskAward, expenditureType, amount**
1122, 12345-67-89, Supplies, 100
1122, 12345-67-89, Supplies, 150
1122, 12345-67-89, Supplies, 250
1122, 12345-67-89, Misc, 50
1122, 12345-67-89, Misc, 100
1122, 98765-43-21, General, 200
1122, 98765-43-21, Conference, 500
1122, 98765-43-21, Misc, 300
1122, 98765-43-21, Misc, 100
1122, 98765-43-21, Misc, 100

I want to summarize the amounts by projTaskAward & expenditureType, based on the trackingNumber.  Here is the output I'm looking for:

Proj/Task/Award: **12345-67-89**
Expenditure Type: **Supplies**
Total: **500**

Proj/Task/Award: **12345-67-89**
Expenditure Type: **Misc**
Total: **150**

Proj/Task/Award: **98765-43-21**
Expenditure Type: **General**
Total: **200**

Proj/Task/Award: **98765-43-21**
Expenditure Type: **Conference**
Total: **500**

Proj/Task/Award: **98765-43-21**
Expenditure Type: **Misc**
Total: **500**

I'd appreciate any help anyone can give in steering me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS-SQL Scalar functions return

> a single data value of the type defined in the RETURNS clause [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Can your application parse the data from a string? You could return your result as varchar() and let your application work with it?

```
 IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.ufnGetSummary', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
 DROP FUNCTION ufnGetSummary;
 GO
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetSummary(@TrackingNumber int)
 RETURNS varchar(100)
 AS 

 BEGIN
 DECLARE @ret varchar(100);
 --  
 -- your Select here
 --
RETURN @ret;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Yes, the application can parse the data from the returned string.  The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to calculate the summary info based on the projTaskAward & expenditureType.  I'm a SQL noob.  I need some guidance on creating a SELECT statement and the associated code that will return summary results similar to my example.

Comment: SELECT projTaskAward, expenditureType, SUM(amount) AS 'Total' From Table where trackingNumber ='someValue' Group by projTaskAward, ExpenditureType

Comment: If you have to work more with T-SQL, I strongly recommend to check out this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp Good Luck :)